# Comparing 2 lists together and make a new list

Tags: python, list

So this is my issue:

I have a list of countries (all of them) and a list of the alphabet.

What needs to happen is that when a country (first list) has one or more of the letters in it from the alphabet (second list)

Delete those letters from the alphabet list and add that country that was used to a new list.

Then keep doing this until the x amount countries have been used and all the letters from the alphabet are deleted/used.

Also make sure that the list of countries is less than 14 countries

Return that list of countries.

This is my old code:

```
def alphabet_set(countries):
    list_of_letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
    matching_countries = []
    for country in countries:
        for letter in list_of_letters:
            if letter in country.lower():
                matching_countries.append(country)
                list_of_letters.remove(letter)
                break


    list_of_countries = list(matching_countries)
    # print(f"Matching countries: \n{matching_countries}")
    print(f"Matching countries: \n{list_of_countries}")
    print(f"Remaining characters: \n{list_of_letters}")

    return list_of_countries
```

I know this is not a good approach, because now i have list of countries that are more than 14 countries.

This is my current code:

```
def alphabet_set(countries):
list_of_letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
# matching_countries = set()
matching_countries = []
matching_letters = []
for country in countries:
    for letter in list_of_letters:
        if letter not in matching_letters:
            if letter in country.lower():
                matching_letters.append(letter)
                if country not in matching_countries:
                # matching_countries.add(country)       #this one is also possible but comment out line 84 & 82 and use line 75
                    matching_countries.append(country)



print(f"Matching countries: \n{matching_countries}")
print(f"Matching countries: \n{len(matching_countries)}")
print(f"Remaining characters: \n{matching_letters}")


return matching_countries
```

With this code i got exactly 14 countries in the list.
As you may have noticed, i just started coding.
And the course is giving me exercises on each subject in Python.

I appreciate all the feedback so i can grow/gain more experience in coding.
Thank you for understanding!

Comment: don't post images of code

Comment: Please replace the images with formatted code/text in the question. See also: [ask], [markdown formatting documentation](/editing-help) and [How to format code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/967621)

Comment: Please don't use Python keywords (`list`, `all`) as variable names.

Comment: The problem statement _"when a country (first list) has one or more of the letters in it from the alphabet (second list) put that in a list and return the list"_ sound really weird: How can the country data look like?

Answer (score 0):

The approach that you need to take is a [greedy one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm), i.e., at each iteration you need to find the country that removes the most of the remaining letters from the alphabet. To do this it's useful to make use of Python [`set`s](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set). If you create a set from a string, it will contain a set of unique characters within that string, e.g.,:

```py
country = set("india")
print(country)
{'a', 'n', 'd', 'i'}
```

With sets you can also easily work out [unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) (the [`|`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union) operator), [intersections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) (the [`&`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) operator) and differences (the [`-`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference) operator) between sets.

Here is an approach (with a smaller list of countries) that you can take:

```py
# import the list of lowercase ascii Latin alphabet characters
from string import ascii_lowercase

# create a set of the alphabet
alphabet = set(ascii_lowercase)

# a list of countries
countries = [
    "india",
    "china",
    "france",
    "spain",
    "germany",
    "qatar",
    "mexico",
    "japan",
    "thailand",
    "argentina",
    "brazil",
    "nigeria",
    "chad",
    "chile",
    "switzerland",
    "togo",
    "new zealand",
    "canada",
    "vanuatu",
    "slovakia",
    "jamaica",
    "sudan",
    "peru",
    "united kingdom",
    "egypt",
    "ukraine",
    "greece",
]

# list that will be filled in with country names
matching_countries = []

# create a while loop that continues until all alphabet characters have been used
while len(alphabet) > 0:
    # create a list of sets of country letters that are in the
    # current alphabet
    countrysets = [
        set(country.replace(" ", "").lower()) & alphabet
        for country in countries
    ]

    # get the number of unique characters in each country
    setlengths = [len(country) for country in countrysets]

    # get the maximum length
    maxlen = max(setlengths)

    # get the list index of the country with the largest length (or first one
    # if there are several equal length ones)
    for i in range(len(countrysets)):
        if setlengths[i] == maxlen:
            argmax = i
            break

    # remove used characters from the alphabet
    alphabet = alphabet - countrysets[argmax]

    # put the country into the matching countries list
    matching_countries.append(countries.pop(argmax))

print(matching_countries)

['switzerland', 'united kingdom', 'china', 'japan', 'france', 'germany', 'qatar', 'mexico', 'brazil', 'vanuatu']
```

Just to double check that this list contains all the Latin alphabet characters we can do:

```py
set("".join(country.replace(" ", "") for country in matching_countries)) == set(ascii_lowercase)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't an optimisation problem (i.e. maximise/minimise the number of countries that exhaust the alphabet), then you could try:

```py
def alphabet_set(countries):
    letters = set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    matches = []
    for country in countries:
        if match := letters.intersection(country.lower()):
            matches.append(country)
            letters -= match
            if len(matches) == 13 or not letters:
                break
    print(f"Matching countries:\n{', '.join(matches) if matches else 'None'}")
    print(f"Remaining letters:\n{', '.join(sorted(letters)) if letters else 'None'}")
    return matches
```

- Don't use a list for the alphabet, use a set instead because it makes the processing much easier: `letters`.
- Iterate over the countries and intersect its characters with the remaining `letters`: If the intersection `match` is not empty, then:

  - append the country to the results list `matches`, and
  - remove the corresponding characters from `letters`.
  - If the number of matching countries is 13 or there are not more letters, break out of the loop.